# Searching XML element in whole document with Groovy XmlParser

Tags: xml, groovy

I'm using the Groovy `XmlParser` to read some XML document. This works fine as long as I know where the elements are located in the tree. However I haven't yet found a way to search the whole XML document for an element like e.g. in XPath `//ElementName`.

What's the Groovy way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking for something like this?

```
def xml = 
'''
<root>
    <parent>
        <child>
            <firstName>John</firstName>
            <lastName>Doe</lastName>
        </child>
        <child>
            <firstName>Tony</firstName>
            <lastName>Stark</lastName>
        </child>
        <child>
            <firstName>Captain</firstName>
            <lastName>America</lastName>
        </child>
    </parent>
</root>
'''

def parsed = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
assert ['John', 'Tony', 'Captain'] == 
          parsed.depthFirst().findAll { it.name() == 'firstName' }*.text()
```

also (as mentioned by Tim) you can use `'**'` for `depthFirst` search

```
assert ['John', 'Tony', 'Captain'] == 
          parsed.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'firstName' }*.text()
```

Comment: You can also do `parsed.'**'.findAll...` for the same result